# Is viewModel necessary to use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to know that is viewModel necessary to use. Is there any alternative of ViewModel.

can I use only xml files for UI.

Comment: You're going to have to use at least a Fragment or a View in order to write your code, just XML is just a layout description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Model View ViewModel (MVVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) is a software architectural pattern so no its not necessary you can just throw everything in your activity/fragment if you wanted and it would work the same but typically you don't want to do that. There are a bunch of different patterns that you can use.

For your second question yes you can only use xml files to create your layout

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible to make application. But I recommend for you to use Android Architecture Components including `ViewModel` by google.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **No**, it's not necessary you can make complete Application Architecture by using fragments but in this way you might face many problems.

[Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture)

you can use the only **XML** for **UI**